# Vim not accepting alt-sequences as fast keycodes

Tags: vim

When I bind `<M-W>` or `<A-W>` they do not get recognized, Vim instead will perform `<ESC>w` (which just moves forward a word).

I even do have this:

```
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=100
```

How can I debug this? I know I can use a special key (like `<F37>`) to get a fast binding, but I'm going to run out of those F-keys eventually, though hopefully 25 bindings should be enough.

It basically doesn't seem like I have the ability to do any binding of anything via `<A->` or `<M->`.

I am averse to doing `nnoremap`<kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>Alt+W</kbd> as that will insert `^[w` which will cause the dreaded delay in processing the escape key (this is a traditional slow key bind).

Comment: Ctrl/Meta (alt) dependant keybinds is generally a bad idea in Vim because it doesn't work on all environments (terminals, encodings, terminal environments and so forth). That being said, you can see what your keystroke is interpreted as when doing Ctrl+v<keystroke> in insert mode.

Comment: My question states rather explicitly how I have already tested Ctrl+V to obtain the terminal sequence sent.

Comment: Just don't use `<A-` or `<M-` mappings: their support is spotty at best. `<leader>` is the way to go.

Comment: I'll move on to sequential bindings as a last resort once I have exhausted alt-bindings (which I will continue to do using fast terminal maps via the high valued F keys) because they introduce that disambiguation delay. Also, preference applied to keys toward the left side of the keyboard for shortcuts so that they can be used without the mousing hand.

Comment: You could add your leader to the left side of the keyboard. As for this "mouse hand" you speak of I don't know what you mean, this is Vim isn't it? ;-)

Comment: Sure. I just think it is good to leave some room for a hybrid approach to productivity. Hence a **preference** for combinations that do not require both hands. There is surely enough key sequence variation that can be combinatorially extracted out of just the left side of the keyboard.